# Access user's OneDrive data using REST API

Tags: onedrive

how to access the user's OneDrive data by using Office 365 API and Administrator OAuth token of the particular domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Graph to get data from various Office 365 services with a single REST end point.

[Here's the reference for OneDrive](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive)

An example REST URL, to get the files at the root of the signed in user's OneDrive, would be:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`

And the resulting JSON might look like:

```
{
  "value": [
    {"name": "myfile.jpg", "size": 2048, "file": {} },
    {"name": "Documents", "folder": { "childCount": 4} },
    {"name": "Photos", "folder": { "childCount": 203} },
    {"name": "my sheet(1).xlsx", "size": 197 }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://..."
}
```